# Is there any way to find the source of Dataset?

Tags: machine-learning, dataset, data-science

I have a Dataset which one I collected from Github.com. But I don't know what is the real source of this Dataset. So is there any way to find the source of this dataset?

Answer (score -1):

Yes Know can Find Datasets from Following-

1.Kaggle.

2.Just Type Dataset on Google you may find some links

Comment: Please read the question again.  OP *has* a data set, but wants to research the original source.